# Using dplyr filter in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm in the early stages of building a Shiny app to plot some data based on user selections.  My data begins:

```
Price,Mileage,Make,Model,Trim,Type,Cylinder,Liter,Doors,Cruise,Sound,Leather
17314.10313,8221,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,1
17542.03608,9135,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,0
16218.84786,13196,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,0
16336.91314,16342,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,0,0
16339.17032,19832,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,0,1
15709.05282,22236,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,0
15230.00339,22576,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,0
15048.04218,22964,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,0
14862.09387,24021,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,0,1
15295.01827,27325,Buick,Century,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.1,4,1,1,1
21335.85248,10237,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
20538.08751,15066,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,0
20512.09409,16633,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,0
19924.15905,19800,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
19774.24907,23359,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
19344.16554,23765,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,0
19105.13012,24008,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
18543.42705,26034,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
17808.199,32896,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,0
17968.83828,34665,Buick,Lacrosse,CX Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
22358.87768,8970,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,0
23785.92253,10577,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
22926.09037,14363,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
21895.75878,16508,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
21273.06171,18908,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
21460.01395,19467,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
21183.12359,21394,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
20406.0995,22596,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
21058.13958,24469,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
19556.89932,25245,Buick,Lacrosse,CXL Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,0
23447.68656,15755,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
23547.23944,16235,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
23016.00801,18147,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
22230.0275,22102,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
22625.07357,23612,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
21799.1721,24439,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
21341.25721,25212,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
21683.03146,26779,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
20986.01602,27096,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
20902.10379,29649,Buick,Lacrosse,CXS Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
20698.07708,2992,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
20099.25684,10036,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
18145.12649,18339,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
17944.85692,19592,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
19027.86231,21797,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
18348.89857,23852,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
17750.88457,25040,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
17772.96968,25052,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
17394.0214,25464,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
17645.74504,27830,Buick,Lesabre,Custom Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
21908.36662,17353,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
21956.34266,17787,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
21646.11692,19562,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
21575.45683,20137,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
20952.2178,20158,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
21562.04758,23767,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
19981.12791,24323,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
19425.84862,27839,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
19191.98962,29187,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
19641.7419,31324,Buick,Lesabre,Limited Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
25589.98315,2308,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
25098.62906,10014,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
23420.70695,18910,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
22661.04849,20105,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
23493.0823,20453,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
22435.20282,22287,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
21878.12,23237,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
23077.56591,23798,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
21698.01475,25489,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
21831.82292,25564,Buick,Park Avenue,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
26831.19404,4695,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
26060.33535,9795,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
26781.81465,12052,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
26302.07428,13050,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
26190.27147,17335,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
25508.21096,17480,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,0
23348.01695,24027,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
23406.68982,25387,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,1
23159.54378,25869,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,0,0
21536.74173,37128,Buick,Park Avenue,Special Ed Ultra 4D,Sedan,6,3.8,4,1,1,1
51154.04722,2202,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,1,1
49248.15897,6685,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,0,1
46747.67327,15343,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,1,1
44130.61706,21341,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,0,1
44084.91421,21367,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,1,1
43892.46788,23371,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,0,1
44300.63996,23751,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,0,1
42677.60112,24052,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,0,1
43374.05242,25199,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,1,1
40619.07227,30082,Cadillac,CST-V,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,5.7,4,1,1,1
33417.96501,6598,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
30957.08075,10625,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
31431.13037,11013,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
30781.51563,14937,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
30646.4377,17094,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
30792.14903,17870,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
30392.75016,18449,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
28817.08185,21039,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,0,1
29275.20871,21056,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
28040.12853,27484,Cadillac,CTS,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,2.8,4,1,1,1
39801.55135,14095,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
40335.73731,14743,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
39307.00916,16041,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
38600.23956,17138,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
38445.89717,18661,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
36077.79612,21966,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
35866.58271,24415,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
35338.65369,25163,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
36154.30355,25339,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
34685.66298,25421,Cadillac,Deville,DHS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
42820.32902,5499,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
41378.04809,8125,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
40856.3909,12791,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
41419.03726,14452,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
37510.25357,21593,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
37215.16938,22211,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
36332.89469,25153,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
36245.15823,26250,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
32954.14134,36074,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
32537.18675,41829,Cadillac,Deville,DTS Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
35715.76856,6447,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
35651.68002,10555,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
35129.34077,11975,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
35165.75937,13449,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
32501.24519,17508,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
33220.02845,18661,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
32509.47829,20910,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
31132.21349,23124,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
31181.71516,26222,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
31059.18103,27544,Cadillac,Deville,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
42741.52367,2846,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
40966.60741,7476,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
38795.37909,13973,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
38297.46254,16754,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
37192.89637,19100,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
36210.123,21778,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,0,1
36633.63382,22042,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
35895.49941,23056,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
34974.37804,25796,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
32038.33956,35326,Cadillac,STS-V6,Sedan 4D,Sedan,6,3.6,4,1,1,1
48310.32954,788,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
48365.9809,2616,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
45061.95194,13829,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
44205.87588,15104,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
42377.95544,18581,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
41671.58314,20575,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
41516.42986,23861,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
41053.48217,25717,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
38208.50102,31303,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,1,1
39072.39205,31587,Cadillac,STS-V8,Sedan 4D,Sedan,8,4.6,4,1,0,1
70755.46672,583,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
68566.18719,6420,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
69133.73172,7892,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
66374.30704,12021,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
65281.48124,15600,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
63913.11725,18200,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
60567.54909,23193,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
57154.44344,29260,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
55639.08765,31805,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,0,1
52001.99438,42691,Cadillac,XLR-V8,Hardtop Conv 2D,Convertible,8,4.6,2,1,1,1
12146.18803,10011,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
12163.82042,12101,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
11472.02276,19699,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
11017.16871,20100,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
11096.85727,20334,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,0,0
10386.04022,22225,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,0
11137.04565,22484,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11045.10884,24568,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,0,1
10777.05254,27906,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,0
9928.188175,29680,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
12649.11089,3629,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
12314.59122,4142,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
11318.00809,11156,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
12409.94909,11981,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
11555.2674,13404,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,1,0
11700.11149,15253,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,0,0
11215.01865,19945,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,0,0
10144.95208,23963,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,1,0
10491.0752,30948,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
9954.054174,37345,Chevrolet,AVEO,LS Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11031.12993,20156,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11343.05401,20186,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
11391.21372,21421,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11247.86253,21427,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
10921.94537,23119,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11179.95357,23121,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11394.8864,25107,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11070.06064,25476,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
11013.87137,25746,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
11115.01364,30056,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
11918.45607,7278,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,0,0
12408.80615,10213,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
11302.90299,14627,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
11615.02102,19014,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
10805.13009,21013,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
11169.91839,22380,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
10770.10655,25065,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
10872.01393,25869,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,0,0
10921.94537,27776,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,1,0,0
9919.048185,34621,Chevrolet,AVEO,LT Sedan 4D,Sedan,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
10813.34352,266,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,0,1
11167.861,4716,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,0
10897.07651,6699,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,1
10106.01643,14200,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,0,0
10354.04385,14521,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,1,0
10287.97736,16521,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,1
9720.97889,20836,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,1,1,0
9506.047937,22169,Chevrolet,AVEO,SVM Hatchback 4D,Hatchback,4,1.6,4,0,0,1
```

The whole thing is too big to post, but this should be sufficient.

My ui.R file contains

```
library(shiny)


data <- read.csv("Amstat.csv", header = TRUE)
modelTypes <- unique(data$Model)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Car prices"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Model", 
                  label = "Choose a Model to display",
                  choices = modelTypes),

      selectInput("price",
                  label = "Choose a price",
                  choices = list("Left","Center", "Right"),
                  selected="CENTER")


    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("carpricePlot")
    )
  )
))
```

And my server.r contains

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- read.csv("Amstat.csv", header = TRUE)
  amstat1<-data %>% select(Type,Price,Model )%>% filter(Model == input$Model)

  output$carpricePlot <- renderPlot({

    plot(Model,
         Price,
         xlab="Model",
         ylab="prirce",
         pch=20)

  })
})
```

When I try to run the app, I get an error message

> Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) :    Operation not allowed without
>   an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only
>   be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I'm not grasping something.  In other apps I've written as I try to learn Shiny I've accomplished basically the same thing using subset instead of filter...should I just avoid filter in Shiny?  Or am I doing something wrong?  Well, clearly I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: `input$Model` can not be used outside of a reactive function (`renderPlot`IS a reactive function, put the code that contains `input$Model` inside - or better : create a `reactive()` that you reference inside the `renderPlot`)

Comment: Thanks!  I see now.  I had tried creating a reactive but I had placed it in the wrong place...inside shinyServer but before renderPlot.  Moving it inside renderPlot cleared it up.  However, I'm still not clear on why a reactive is necessary when using filter but not when using subset....If you'll make your original comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: For future reference, use dput to share datasets so people can just copy and paste it to replicate your work

Comment: Will do...I was not familiar with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a variable from UI (`input$...`), you must do it in a reactive:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- read.csv("Amstat.csv", header = TRUE)
  amstat1<-reactive({
    data %>% select(Type,Price,Model ) %>% filter(Model == input$Model)
    })

  output$carpricePlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(amstat1()$Model,
         amstat1()$Price,
         xlab="Model",
         ylab="Price",
         pch=20)

  })
})
```

Comment: That looks very similar to what I tried and I got an error...something like object of type closure is not subsettable or something like that...I'll go back and take a look.

Comment: @jerH closure is not subsettable arises when you call a reactive without `()`, like `amstat1$Model`

Comment: I could see me making that kind of mistake!  Thanks for providing the translator ring on that error message...